# Array declaration in main method

Tags: java

I was reading and faced with interesting look of main method which I didn't see before. Is there any difference between

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
```

and

```
  public static void main(String a[])
```

As I see applying either of them gives me the same output

```
  public static void main(String a[]){
        List <Integer> li = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        ListIterator <Integer> liItr = null;

        li.add(1);
        li.add(2);
        li.add(3);
        li.add(4);
        li.add(5);
        li.add(6);
        li.add(7);

       liItr = li.listIterator();
       System.out.println("Elemnets in forward direction");
       while(liItr.hasNext()){
           System.out.println(liItr.next());
       }
       System.out.println("Elements in backward direction");
       while(liItr.hasPrevious()){
           System.out.println(liItr.previous());
      }
    }
  }
```

P.S. I consider myself as a beginner of Java. If someone could highlight giving me some explanation on that it would be nice

Comment: In _that_ declaration, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no difference. The only *difference* is the array declaration:

```
String[] args
```

vs

```
String a[]
```

Both are valid.

From [Java Language Specification. Chapter 10. Arrays. 10.2. Array Variables.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) (emphasis mine):

> Example 10.2-1. Declarations of Array Variables
>
> ```
> int[]     ai;        // array of int
> short[][] as;        // array of array of short
> short     s,         // scalar short
>           aas[][];   // array of array of short
> Object[]  ao,        // array of Object
>           otherAo;   // array of Object
> Collection<?>[] ca;  // array of Collection of unknown type
> ```
>
> The `[]` **may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.**
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];
> ```
>
> This declaration is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> byte rowvector[], colvector[], matrix[][];
> ```

Answer (score 2):

From  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2

> The `[]` may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the
>   declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable,
>   or both.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> byte[] rowvector...
> ```
>
> This declaration is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> byte rowvector[]...
> ```

BTW, not many realize that **unfortunately** this rule affects also `Type` `methodSignature` pair, not only `Type` `variable`. So something like

```
int giveMeArray()[]{
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - method signature
        return new int[10];
}
```

is also valid Java code.

Anyway this way of declaring array can be useful if you would like to create... lets say 2 and 3 dimensional arrays. So instead of

```
int[][] arr2d;
int[][][] arr3d;
```

you can just write

```
int[][] arr2d, arr3d[];
//                  ^^-additional dimension
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting but harder-to-read-and-maintain example about array declaration for methods. I feel good for not realizing that, though.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a difference.  See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html which states this: "You can also place the brackets after the array's name:", but suggests it is bad form.

Comment: @KickButtowski it is not wrong (in terms of content), but you cannot add that kind of info in other user's answer unless it is community wiki. You can post a comment advising this user to improve the answer and tell how, or write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

`String[] args` is as valid as `String args[]` and as `String a[]`.

Java has **no restriction regarding arguments naming** and authorizes **both styles of array declaration syntaxes** (brackets after or before the variable name) => Matter of taste.

Comment: See the link I provided above. Java says it is not a matter of taste.

Comment: @jordan Bad != Discouraged.  There isn't any difference at all, just a better way for developer to not forget that he deals with an array. So it is clearly a matter of taste.